# ajax to php post - all sent and received but php fails

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have checked other questions. **This is not a duplicate.**
All seems ok, data is posted and received by php but something went wrong reading the whole post.
What's rare in this case is that it fails sometimes not always. I try and works then after a while I try again and it happens again (post not read by php), then wait try again and it works. This random behaviour is very hard to debug.

I will show below what happens when there is the error (post not read by php).

Html

```
<input type="file" id="file">
```

My ajax code

```
var file_contents = $( '#file' )[0].files[0];
var id ='2';    

var form_data = new FormData(); 
form_data.append( 'id', id );   
form_data.append( "file", file_contents );

$.ajax( {
contentType: false, 
processData: false,     
cache: false,
type: 'POST',
url: 'upload.php',
data: form_data,
success: function ( dataresp ) {        
}
});
```

Looking at the **developers tools** of my browser the **post looks fine**.

```
-----------------------------3281079916952851611992156178
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="id"

2
-----------------------------3281079916952851611992156178
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="33.png"
Content-Type: image/png

PNG

[I removed here the file contents, too long]

-----------------------------3281079916952851611992156178--
```

upload.php - The php code very simple.

```
<?php
print $_POST['id'];
print $_FILES['file']['name'];
```

But both php $_POST and $_FILES are empty. 
What could I loom for to understand why php in not receiving data? **See below!**

Then I tried this in upload.php:

```
<?php

print file_get_contents("php://input");
```

The response is exactly what I see in the post above. 
Why php is not reading this post then?

THEN I TRIED TO USE **GET** IN AJAX.

The response of var_dump($_GET); is the following:

```
array(1) {
  ["_"]=>
  string(13) "1576863920768"
}
```

I'm sure I'm missing something silly, but it's driving me crazy!! :(

Comment: You pass `id` and `file` keys in formdata. How come that you check for `teamid` and `s3_file`?

Comment: That's a mistake in the post I will fix this

Comment: try something like this in the server side: `if ($_POST) {print_r($_POST)} else {echo 'got nothing!'}` and see what happens?

Comment: Try this : success: function (data ) {  data:data or data
}

Comment: Yes returns "got nothing!"

Comment: Your description is kind of confusing. So you actually get some data from the `$_GET` variable and want this value?

Answer (score 0):

It was silly. It looks like solved with jQuery.noConflict();